# If $\langle \alpha,\dot \alpha\rangle(\theta+c_1)-\langle \alpha,\dot \alpha\rangle(\theta)=c_2$, does $c_2=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry, curves, symmetry

Let $\alpha:ֿ\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a $C^2$ curve  satisfying $|\dot \alpha|=1$. Define $b=\langle \alpha,\dot \alpha\rangle$ and assume that
$$
b(\theta+c_1)-b(\theta)=c_2 \tag{1}
$$
holds for every $\theta$, where $c_1,c_2$ are constants. Does $c_2=0$?

(If $c_2=0$, then a "rotation" by $c_1$ is a sort of "symmetry" of $\alpha$.)

---

Differentiating equation $(1)$ we get $\dot b(\theta+c_1)=\dot b(\theta)$. Since $\dot b=1+\langle \alpha,\ddot \alpha\rangle$, this is equivalent to
$$
\langle \alpha,\ddot \alpha\rangle(\theta)=\langle \alpha,\ddot \alpha\rangle(\theta+c_1).
$$

I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Presumably $c_1\neq 2k\pi$ too?

Comment: Yes, one can require that. But actually, this isn't necessary: If $c_1=2\pi k$, then trivially $c_2=0$. So I removed the requirement $c_1 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the answer is positive:

Write $f(t)=|\alpha(t)|^2$. Then $f'=2b$.

Our assumption is equivalent to
$$
f'(t+c_1)-f'(t)=2c_2.
$$
Since $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic, we have
$$
0=\int_{0}^{2\pi} f'(t)dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi} f'(t+c_1)dt.
$$
Since
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} f'(t+c_1)dt-\int_{0}^{2\pi} f'(t)dt=4\pi c_2,
$$
this forces $c_2=0$.